# How to improve list component with service?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a component that renders array of items and allow to select item:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-sortring',
    templateUrl: './sortring.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./sortring.component.scss'],
})
export class SortringComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() fields: SortField[] = [];
    @Input() selected: SortField[] = [];

    public onSelect = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);

    constructor(private ListService: ListService) {}

    public select(value: ListItem): void {
        this.ListService.set(value);
        this.onSelect.next(this.ListService.get());
    }

    public isSelected(value: ListItem): boolean {
        return this.ListService.selected(value);
    }

    public drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
        moveItemInArray(this.fields, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.fields);
    }
}
```

This component uses service that `get/set/check` array:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ListItem } from '../models/listitem';

@Injectable()
export class ListService {
    private selectedItems: ListItem[] = [];
    private items: ListItem[] = [];

    selected(value: ListItem): boolean {
        return this.selectedItems.includes(value);
    }

    get(): ListItem[] {
        return this.selectedItems;
    }

    set(value: ListItem): void {
        if (this.selected(value)) {
            this.selectedItems = this.selectedItems.filter((item) => item !== value);
        } else {
            this.selectedItems = [...this.selectedItems, value];
        }
    }
}
```

My questions are with subquestion:

1. How to improve this component, I mean should I move `public onSelect = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);` to service?
2. Whats should be placed in service also to make component more independend and reusable?
3. Should I use:

> ```
> @Input() fields: SortField[] = [];
> @Input() selected: SortField[] = [];
> ```

Or move it to service?

I need a critica!

Comment: I prefer move all logic to service it follows one responsibility principle and in any time you can change presentation component. But maybe more skilled developers thinks differently

Comment: What about Input? Because I can read selected items from service instead using Input?

Comment: Would be creat to see how do this professionanals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have a Subject on the ListService and subscribe to that Subject on every component that may need it. Everytime you select an item, you can emit the updated list. Keep all the logic in the ListService.

I don't see a problem in using @Input() for the SortFields array, as long as you expect it to change depending on where you set the component, per example. But, if you will always use the same sort fields, and if they are coupled to the ListService, I would store them there - it will be easier to modify in the future.

Finally, your component is very lean, so I wouldn't change it further.

Comment: Could you explain more about: Everytime you select an item, you can emit the updated list. Keep all the logic in the ListService. Do you mean return selected items or modified array?

Comment: @Jessy When an item is selected your component calls a method on your ListService which handles all logic about selecting an item. Then, on your ListService you can emit an array with copies of all selected item (eg. yourSubject.next(yourSelectedItemsArr) ). I prefer to return a copy to reduce side effects, like a component modifying the list.

Comment: Do you mean yourSelectedItemsArr and yourItemsArr the same type?

Comment: @Jessy That could be one way to do it, yes.

Comment: Could you share exmaple of service?